# UWP StorageFolder GetFilesAsync() not returning

Tags: c#, uwp

I have updated my visual studio 2017 to the creators update SDK **16299**. But ever since I cannot use the `StorageFolder` to get files. The execution doesn't return and no exception is thrown.

```
 try
 {
     var instalationFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
     var assetFolder = await instalationFolder.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
     var files = await assetFolder.GetFilesAsync();
     var count = files.Count;
 }
 catch (Exception ex){}
```

Please advice,  the execution disappears at assetFolder.GetFilesAsync()

Comment: This is the same issue that I faced after installation of the Insider build 16299.. Just update you windows to the latest insider build or revert to your previous build and it should work as expected.. Note : My issue was due to version of windows.. reverting your visual studio sdk might help too..

Comment: The [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK (16299)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/10/11/windows-10-fall-creators-update-sdk/) is the correct version to use. What version of the OS are you running?

Comment: My OS is insider Preview build 17040.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn My OS is insider Preview build 17040

Comment: @Pratyay ~ I suspected the same thing. The difference in SDK and OS version.

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated my SDK to match the version of my Insider Preview and now everything is working great.

Comment: I am using FCU with the correct SDK, however I am still getting this issue. I don't see this issue if I target CU. Using VS 15.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I updated my SDK to match the version of my Insider Preview and now everything is working great. Turns out the OS build and SDK version were out of sync, I downloaded the SDK for 17040 and now I can use the StorageFolder API's