# CreateFileAsync freezes app

Tags: c#, file, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to get one line of code working in a Windows 10 UWP.

```
private static async Task MakeFile()
{
  var file = await 
  Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("bob", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
}
```

For some reason When I try to run this the whole app freezes and never comes back

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524306/uwp-storagefolder-getfilesasync-not-returning#comment82004775_47524306

Comment: It does not seem to be the same issue as the one you posted. My SDK versions match the OS.

Comment: Can you specify the version ? is it by any chance 16299 ?

Comment: Yes it is 16299

Comment: just update your OS or SDK to the next version and this issue will go away.. there was a known bug in 16299 which got fixed in the next builds..

Comment: my OS and SDK both show they are up to date.so how do I update them?

Comment: @GaryHengeveld Pratyay meant that you need to join in the [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/getting-started/) to get the insider preview version.

Comment: Yes, as @Bite mentioned you can either get the insider build or you can wait for the next stable version.

Comment: But that is actually weird. This freeze bug appeared in older insider preview builds, but 16299 is the stable FCU version and I have no such issues running 16299 and 16299 SDK together, and the code sample runs just fine. It definitely shouldn't be necessary to install the Insider preview.

Comment: Have you tried to run the app without debugging? Does that change the behavior?

Comment: @GaryHengeveld do you try run it on UI Thread ?

Comment: I didn't want to update beyond the stable version. I tried without debugging and on the main thread with no luck. So I created a new project and tried it there and it worked fine. So I just redid the app and copied my code over and now it works. Something must have gotten corrupt in that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to update beyond the stable version. I tried without debugging and on the main thread with no luck. So I created a new project and tried it there and it worked fine. So I just redid the app and copied my code over and now it works. Something must have gotten corrupt in that project